# Boost Beast Read Conent By Portions

Tags: c++, http, boost, boost-beast

I am trying to understand how can I limit the amount of data that is read from the internet by calling 'read_some' function in boost beast.

The starting point is the [incremental read](https://github.com/boostorg/beast/blob/b7344b0d501f23f763a76488826dde8c31f34b5d/test/doc/http_examples.cpp#L250) example in the beast's docs.
From the docs I understood that the really read data is stored in the flat_buffer.
I make the following experiment:

1. Set max flat_buffer's size to 1024
2. Connect to a relatively large (several KB) html page
3. Call read_some one time
4. Turn the internet off
5. Try to read the page to the end

Since buffer's capacity is not large enough to store the entire page, my experiment should fail - I should not be able to read the entire page. Nevertheless, it finishes successfully. That means that there exists some additional buffer where the read data is stored. But what is it made for and how can I limit its size?

**UPD**
Here is my source code:

```
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/version.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/strand.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

namespace beast = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http = beast::http;           // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace net = boost::asio;            // from <boost/asio.hpp>

using namespace http;

template<
        bool isRequest,
        class SyncReadStream,
        class DynamicBuffer>
void
read_and_print_body(
        std::ostream& os,
        SyncReadStream& stream,
        DynamicBuffer& buffer,
        boost::beast::error_code& ec ) {
    parser<isRequest, buffer_body> p;
    read_header( stream, buffer, p, ec );
    if ( ec )
        return;
    while ( !p.is_done()) {
        char buf[512];
        p.get().body().data = buf;
        p.get().body().size = sizeof( buf );
        read_some( stream, buffer, p, ec );
        if ( ec == error::need_buffer )
            ec = {};
        if ( ec )
            return;
        os.write( buf, sizeof( buf ) - p.get().body().size );
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        // Check command line arguments.
        if(argc != 4 && argc != 5)
        {
            std::cerr <<
            "Usage: http-client-sync <host> <port> <target> [<HTTP version: 1.0 or 1.1(default)>]\n" <<
            "Example:\n" <<
            "    http-client-sync www.example.com 80 /\n" <<
            "    http-client-sync www.example.com 80 / 1.0\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        auto const host = argv[1];
        auto const port = argv[2];
        auto const target = argv[3];
        int version = argc == 5 && !std::strcmp("1.0", argv[4]) ? 10 : 11;

        // The io_context is required for all I/O
        net::io_context ioc;

        // These objects perform our I/O
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(ioc);
        beast::tcp_stream stream(ioc);

        // Look up the domain name
        auto const results = resolver.resolve(host, port);

        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        stream.connect(results);

        // Set up an HTTP GET request message
        http::request<http::string_body> req{http::verb::get, target, version};
        req.set(http::field::host, host);
        req.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);

        // Send the HTTP request to the remote host
        http::write(stream, req);

        // This buffer is used for reading and must be persisted
        beast::flat_buffer buffer;

        boost::beast::error_code ec;
        read_and_print_body<false>(std::cout, stream, buffer, ec);
    }
    catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The example doesn't use `read_some`. The relevant Beast interfaces do not have this member. What are you doing, *exactly*?

Comment: @sehe I have updated the question and added the source code there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operating system's TCP IP stack obviously needs to buffer data, so that's likely where it gets buffered.

The way to test your desired scenario:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0801d6a527ac7ebb)**

```
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
namespace net = boost::asio;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http = beast::http;
using net::ip::tcp;

void server()
{
    net::io_context ioc;
    tcp::acceptor acc{ioc, {{}, 8989}};
    acc.listen();

    auto conn = acc.accept();

    http::request<http::string_body> msg(
        http::verb::get, "/", 11, std::string(20ull << 10, '*'));
    msg.prepare_payload();

    http::request_serializer<http::string_body> ser(msg);

    size_t hbytes = write_header(conn, ser);
    // size_t bbytes = write_some(conn, ser);
    size_t bbytes = write(conn, net::buffer(msg.body(), 1024));

    std::cout << "sent " << hbytes << " header and " << bbytes << "/"
              << msg.body().length() << " of body" << std::endl;
    // closes connection
}

namespace {
    template<bool isRequest, class SyncReadStream, class DynamicBuffer>
        auto
        read_and_print_body(
                std::ostream& /*os*/,
                SyncReadStream& stream,
                DynamicBuffer& buffer,
                boost::beast::error_code& ec)
        {
            struct { size_t hbytes = 0, bbytes = 0; } ret;

            http::parser<isRequest, http::buffer_body> p;
            //p.header_limit(8192);
            //p.body_limit(1024);

            ret.hbytes = read_header(stream, buffer, p, ec);
            if(ec)
                return ret;
            while(! p.is_done())
            {
                char buf[512];
                p.get().body().data = buf;
                p.get().body().size = sizeof(buf);
                ret.bbytes += http::read_some(stream, buffer, p, ec);
                if(ec == http::error::need_buffer)
                    ec = {};
                if(ec)
                    break;
                //os.write(buf, sizeof(buf) - p.get().body().size);
            }
            return ret;
        }
}

void client()
{
    net::io_context ioc;
    tcp::socket conn{ioc};
    conn.connect({{}, 8989});

    beast::error_code ec;
    beast::flat_buffer buf;
    auto [hbytes, bbytes] = read_and_print_body<true>(std::cout, conn, buf, ec);

    std::cout << "received hbytes:" << hbytes << " bbytes:" << bbytes
              << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::jthread s(server);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::jthread c(client);
}
```

Prints

```
sent 41 header and 1024/20480 of body
received 1065 bytes of message (partial message)
```

### Side Notes

You start your question with:

> I am trying to understand how can I limit the amount of data that is read from the internet

That's built in to Beast

> by calling 'read_some' function in boost beast.

To just limit the total amount of data read, you don't have to use `read_some` in a loop (`http::read` by definition already does exactly that).

E.g. with the above example, if you replace `20ull<<10` (20 KiB) with `20ull<<20` (20 MiB) you will exceed the default size limit:

```
http::request<http::string_body> msg(http::verb::get, "/", 11,
                                     std::string(20ull << 20, '*'));
```

Prints **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd8f2ccefb2fe96a)**

```
sent 44 header and 1024/20971520 of body
received hbytes:44 bbytes:0 (body limit exceeded)
```

You can also set your own parser limits:

```
http::parser<isRequest, http::buffer_body> p;
p.header_limit(8192);
p.body_limit(1024);
```

Which prints [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b8d917d4ed64754):

sent 41 header and 1024/20480 of body
received hbytes:41 bbytes:0 (body limit exceeded)

As you can see it even knows to reject the request after just reading the headers, using the `content-length` information from the headers.

Comment: Such an approach does not allow to read more than 1024 of body. My purpose is to be able to read arbitrary amount of information but with calling the corresponding number of ```read_some``` functions: say every second I call ```read_some``` function or stop my algo. I would like the total amount of read data not to exceed buffer_size * number of read_some calls. Of course I understand that it is impossible to guarantee that it does not exceed at all but at least does not exceed too much

Comment: Still the same answer to me, updated [the answer & example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72522923/revisions) to use the question code

Comment: You say that "http::read by definition already does exactly that". How does it limit? I mean to which size does it limit to? And if I do not need to use read_some what does this function exist for, which use cases does it cover?

Comment: If I set the body limit, I am not able to read a large amount of data

Comment: Do you want to limit, or not? Did you validate that my answer demonstrate that the buffering works as advertised, as long as you actually control the server to stop sending in time?

Comment: Re: "http::read by definition already does exactly that"  that was **immediately following** the context: _you don't have to use read_some in a loop (http::read by definition already does exactly that)_. To the (probably irrelevant) question "how does it limit" the answer is also in my post: using `header_limit`/`body_limit`.

Comment: `read_some` exists as a building block, but in reality you are encouraged to implement [a Custom Body Type](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_http/custom_body_types.html) instead

Comment: (PS. `read_some` is used when you want to process a body in streaming fashion, e.g. with `buffer_body` - but that couldn't be the question you had because that was in your question from the very start)

Comment: It seems that I do not catch something.. I have no control on the server. I can not use body limit since it limits the entire amount of information received from the server. What I want is to avoid downloading redundant information: ideally the next portion (buffer) of information should be downloaded when I request it

Comment: If you don't control the server, then you already have the optimal situation. You cannot control that the server doesn't already send beyond what the OS's IP stack already implements in terms of flow control. My answer code was intended to demonstrate that this is the case.

Comment: Turns out all that you wanted was "streaming message parsing" (which is pretty different from  _"how can I limit the amount of data that is read from the internet by calling 'read_some' function in boost beast"_). The sample code does already do that. If you want to reduce OS-level buffering, look at the manual for your operating system. I know Linux has some tunables (sysctl I think).

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for incorrect question formulation. But still there are some misunderstandings from my side: for my purposes is it better to use read_some or just read? And does setting limit for the flat_buffer's size change anything?

Comment: Since you want streaming consumption, `read_some` is required. The `flat_buffer` governs how much "read-ahead" might be performed. It seems you can move it inside the `read_and_print_body` function to match its size with the `char[512]` body buffer.

Comment: The reason to supply an external read buffer is in case you read multiple messages in sequence, and some data belonging to the next message might already jave been received into that flat_buffer. The `body()` will never contain "excess" data because the `parser<>` will be `is_done()` when the message is complete, *or* in some HTTP/1.0 until the connection is closed.